# Cancel the dismiss of a DialogFragment after PositiveButton clicked

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I have extended a `DialogFragment`. It just has an `EditText` and Accept and Cancel buttons.

Inside it, a text is entered to an `EditText`; then, upon clicking Accept, the text is checked using `try/catch`.

Inside the `try`, if everything goes fine, I dismiss the dialog; if the flow enters the `catch`, the idea is to retain the dialog and not dismiss it, to give the user the chance to correct the text.

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            onAcceptDialog();
        }
    })
    ...
}

...

private void onAcceptDialog() {
    try {
        ...
        this.dismiss();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ...
        //Dialog is still being dismissed here although it shouldn't
    }
}
```

However, the dialog is still being dismissed although I am not calling `this.dismiss()` inside the `catch`.

**Is there any way to cancel the dismissal once inside `onAcceptDialog()`?**

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue make a custom dialog to solve this problem.

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
{

final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);    
alert.setTitle("Test");
alert.setIcon(R.drawable.logo1);
alert.setMessage("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nam cursus.");
 LinearLayout lila1= new LinearLayout(this);
LinearLayout linbuttons = new LinearLayout(this);
linbuttons.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
Button btnPositive = new Button(this);
Button btnNegative = new Button(this);
btnPositive.setText("Send");
btnPositive.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // write your code for sending
        onBackPressed();
    }
});
btnNegative.setText("Cancel");
btnNegative.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        onBackPressed();
    }
});
linbuttons.addView(btnPositive);
linbuttons.addView(btnNegative);
lila1.addView(linbuttons);

return alert.create();      
} 
}
```

For your [reference.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16358228/why-alertbox-is-closing-after-clicking-ok-button). Hope this will help you.

Comment: I guessed this would be the only choice, but I didn't want to loose the semantics of the Ok and Cancel button... thanks anyway!