# How to display Toast from AlertDialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, toast

When the user clicks on the save button, an `AlertDialog` appears and asks the user to input text for the file name.

If the user clicks the positive button ("Ok") without specifying a name, I want to display a toast which asks them to do so, and keep the `AlertDialog` open. But the toast never displays and the dialog closes.

The code for the `AlertDialog` is here:

```
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alert.setTitle(R.string.save_game);
    alert.setMessage(R.string.request_name);

    // Set an EditText view to get user input 
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    input.setHint(R.string.untitled);
    alert.setView(input);

    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
      String value = input.getText().toString();
      if(value != null){
          // Do something with value      
      }
      else{
          Toast.makeText(context, R.string.no_name_given, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
    }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        // Canceled.
    }
    });

    alert.show();
```

How can I make this happen?

Thanks!

Comment: what is context? is it activity context?

Comment: Yes. The parent activity sets `context = this` in its `onCreate(...)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Public void showToast() {
    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_name_given, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Just call this method instead of displaying toast from an alert dialog box like this in your code.

```
else {
    showToast();
}
```

To keep it open use this method

```
public void forceOpen() {

    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alert.setTitle(R.string.save_game);
    alert.setMessage(R.string.request_name);

    // Set an EditText view to get user input 
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    input.setHint(R.string.untitled);
    alert.setView(input);

    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            String value = input.getText().toString();
            if(value != null) {
                // Do something with value      
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(context, R.string.no_name_given, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            // Canceled.
        }
    });

    alert.show();

}
```

Just reopen it.. Not sure why it closes but this will work

Comment: This displayed the Toast, but did not keep the `AlertDialog` open.

Comment: Hmm not sure why, you never called close. Just reopen it when the user clicks OK.. They won't notice

Comment: I see you put the code into a method. You are suggesting that the method calls itself from within the code for the click on "Ok", in a kind of recursion? The thing is, I don't think that the first `AlertDialog` is destroyed until the click is consumed, so this would likely layer `AlertDialog` on top of `AlertDialog`

Comment: Yes make it a method and have it call itself. And no, I just tried it and it looked natural. There is no other way to do this without creating a custom dialog box from scratch without its own layout

Comment: Okay, I tried it and it works. It seems hacky, but if the only other option is to make a custom dialog I'll take this for now. Thanks!

Comment: Yes it is hacky but if hacky works there's nothing wrong with that. And no problem!

Answer (score 2):

Change the code as follows:

```
if(value != null && value.length()>0){

// Do something with value      
 }else{
          Toast.makeText(context, R.string.no_name_given, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: This displayed the Toast, but did not keep the `AlertDialog` open.

Comment: @Rookatu, did you try the above solution? Hope it would work as your previous if condition was not checking the length of text value.

Comment: Yes, I tried your suggestion. It fixed the issue about the Toast not displaying, but as my above comment stated, it did not keep the `AlertDialog` open. I want to keep it open until the user either inputs a valid file name and presses "Ok", or presses "Cancel".

Comment: AlertDialog will be closed by default when you click on any provided button rt? If you still want to have it, go for custom dialog (dialog with custom layout xml) as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016313/how-to-keep-an-alertdialog-open-after-button-onclick-is-fired

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the Ok button.If the condition is validate,then enable button again.

Comment: If I do this how would I show the Toast when the button is pressed? Or are suggesting that I abandon that idea?

Comment: Yes.You can change your idea.

Comment: Or you can use custom dialog instead of AlertDialog

Answer (score 0):

```
public void alert()
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple, null);

        final EditText etText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.etName);

        final AlertDialog d = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setView(v)
        .setTitle("Warning ..")
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                new Dialog.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int which) 
            {
                //Do nothing here. We override the onclick
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter Text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)
        .create();
        d.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way what worked for me to get Context from AlertDialog's OnClick method using DialogInterface:

> ((Dialog) dialogInterface).getContext()

Using it in OnClick() method:

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
        Toast.makeText(((Dialog) dialogInterface).getContext(), "Bla-bla" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## General Solution

If you want to update anything on Activity from a Dialog this solution might help.
For example, showing a toast message from a Dialog button click.

**Create a listener**

```
public interface YesNoClickListner {

    public void yesClicked();

    public void noClicked();
}
```

**Pass the interface in your dialog**

```
public class FireMissilesDialog extends DialogFragment {

    private YesNoClickListner listner;

    public FireMissilesDialog(YesNoClickListner listner){
        this.listner = listner;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage("This is custom Dialog")
            .setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    listner.yesClicked();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    listner.noClicked();
                }
            });
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

**Implement the listener in your Activity and override methods**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements YesNoClickListner{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FireMissilesDialog fireMissilesDialog = new FireMissilesDialog(this);
        fireMissilesDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"Dialog");

    }

    @Override
    public void yesClicked() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Yes Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void noClicked() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

## Result:

[image]

> This solution may not be exactly what you need to solve this
>   particular question. But this works in general. For example, if you
>   need to update a textView in your Activity on YES button click then
>   just override method this like.

```
@Override
public void yesClicked() {
   Toast.makeText(this, "Yes Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

## Relevant Link:

[Full working code](https://github.com/rohitksingh/My_Android_Garage/tree/master/DialogDemo)