# is there a way to interact with a custom layout inflated in an Alert Dialog?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I have a code which inflates a custom layout inside an Alert Dialog.
The Custom Layout consists of an EditText and a Button. What is the correct way to display the EditText String inside a Toast by clicking the Button ?

[image]

I have tried the below code but it doesn't seem to work.

```java
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setPositiveButton("Fetch", (dialog, which) -> {

}).setNeutralButton("Cancel", (dialog, which) -> {

});

final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);

dialog.setView(dialogLayout);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.show();

dialog.setOnShowListener(d -> {
    EditText dialogNameEditText = dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_name_edittext);
    Button dialogPrintButton = dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_print_button);

    dialogPrintButton.setOnClickListener(v1 -> {
        Toast.makeText(
                TestActivity.this,
                dialogNameEditText.getText().toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show();
    });
});
```

custom_layout.xml file

```xml
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="12dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/dialog_name_edittext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorDark"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorLight" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialog_print_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="Print"
        android:textColor="@color/colorLight" />
    
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what is the problem with your code ? if there are any errors please add them to the question

Comment: @BilalRammal there are no errors in the code, The Toast doesn't show up. Hence I am assuming my implementation must not be correct so generally what is the correct way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Originally answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18009822/how-to-display-toast-from-alertdialog)

Create a separate function for toast

```
public void show_toast(){
Toast.makeText(
                TestActivity.this,
                dialogNameEditText.getText().toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show();
}
```

and in onclicklistener call it

```
dialog.setOnShowListener(d -> {
    EditText dialogNameEditText = dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_name_edittext);
    Button dialogPrintButton = dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_print_button);

    dialogPrintButton.setOnClickListener(v1 -> {
        show_toast();
    });
});
```

Comment: This Method Worked for AlertDialog. Thankyou! 
Why did it work inside a separate function any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple code. it will work.

```
 Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_layout);

    EditText dialogNameEditText = dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_name_edittext);
    Button dialogPrintButton = dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_print_button);
    dialogPrintButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,dialogNameEditText.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
```

Comment: You are welcome. if you have any query related to android development. you can ask me, bro anytime