# How to validate edit text input in Android?

Tags: android, validation, textutils

I've added input validation to a set of edit texts in a dialog message using the `setError` method in Android.

But when I test it by leaving some of the edit texts blank and clicking `"ok"` on the dialog, the dialog closes without triggering a prompt to enter values.

Can anyone see what is wrong with this implementation?

I think it may be something to do with a call to close the dialog before input validation is triggered.

This is how I've set the input validation based on the 4th answer in this question, [Check if EditText is empty.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290531/check-if-edittext-is-empty):

```
    else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(strColour)) {
        colourText.setError("Please enter a value");
        return;
     }
}
   dialog.cancel(); 
}
```

Comment: Why are you setting error in only one edit text `shipText` irrespective of the error location? Copy-paste error probably!

Comment: @Rohit5k2, that was an editing error, the dialog still does not stay open for validation though, if I click "ok" , it still lets the dialog close and doesn't trigger the input validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are calling `dialog.cancel()` irrespective of error(s). Call this method only if there is no error. Keep a track of error using a boolean. If error exist make it false otherwise keep it true and call the `dialog.cancel()` method only if the boolean is true.

Comment: See the code in my answer, it would give you and idea.

Comment: You could create your own custom dialog with a submit button which you can set onClickListener on it then validate when a user clicks it.

Comment: There are some changes you need to make in your code to make it work. This will help you achieve that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016313/how-to-keep-an-alertdialog-open-after-button-onclick-is-fired

Comment: Thats because of default listener. See the link in my last comment.

Comment: Accepted, but this solution will only work on a custom dialog not my implementation.