# How to prevent AlertDialog from closing android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, builder

How to prevent AlertDialog box from closing down when a button is pressed. E.g. Currently when I press "Got it" button the dialog box closes but I don't want it to close, I want it to keep showing up. Basically, I have a button there but I don't want it to close the AlertDialog when pressed.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Message")
        .setMessage("First message")
        .setCancelable(true)
        .setNegativeButton("Got it", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                }});
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
```

Comment: I had the same problem, I think AlertDialog.Builder have this behaviour, I ended up with doing a Dialog that is created later by builder.create();

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent a dialog from closing when a button is clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620444/how-to-prevent-a-dialog-from-closing-when-a-button-is-clicked)

Comment: You can find the answer in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7636468/1830137).

Comment: I already had a look at the links you guys provided but there don't work.

Comment: Try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016313/how-to-keep-an-alertdialog-open-after-button-onclick-is-fired