# AlertDialog dismissed by empty onClick

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

The code below defines an AlertDialog with 2 buttons. Clicking on either button calls the correct `onClick` method. As it is, each method just has a Log statement, yet clicking on either one causes the dialog to be dismissed. Why?

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
builder.setPositiveButton("Dismiss",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Log.d("MyFragment", "Positive button");
            }
        }).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);

builder.setNeutralButton("Send Email",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Log.d("MyFragment", "Neutral button");
            }
        }).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
builder.setMessage("Some message");
builder.setCancelable(false);

Dialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.setTitle("Details");
dialog.setCancelable(false);
dialog.show();
```

Comment: See the second answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016313/how-to-keep-an-alertdialog-open-after-button-onclick-is-fired

Comment: you must note that dialog being dismissed is proper behaviour

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this `.setCancelable(false)`.

**EDIT:** Well, that didn't work, apparently [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620444/how-to-prevent-a-dialog-from-closing-when-a-button-is-clicked) did the trick. ;)

Comment: Crap, my bad, was deep at the bottom, sorry man.

Comment: No problem, we all make mistakes

Comment: @AlLelopath Hey, here, have you seen this? [How to prevent a dialog from closing when a button is clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620444/how-to-prevent-a-dialog-from-closing-when-a-button-is-clicked)

Comment: I did not. I will try it. thanks.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the previous question. That solved it.

Comment: @AlLelopath hey, np man.

Answer (score 1):

The dialog is dismissed because this is its default behaviour. If you want it to remain you could override the onShowListener and set the appropriate button click listeners there.

```
final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface d) {
            dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(...);
        }
    });
```