# Don't close AlertDialog after button is clicked

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I need help!

I'm developing an android app and I ran into a problem.
I have an `AlertDialog` which contains two buttons(positive and negative). When a button is clicked certain code runs, then the dialog is closed.

```
dialog.setNegativeButton("button name", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // some code
        }
    });
```

But that's not what I want. When the users clicks the negative button I want some code to run and then the dialog SHOULDN'T be closed.

```
dialog.setNegativeButton("button name", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // some code
            // code to prevent the dialog from being closed ?
        }
    });
```

Is there anything I can do to prevent the dialog from being closed when the positive or negative button is clicked ?

I tried using this code:

```
dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setEnabled(false);
```

But it doesn't work because now the user can't click the button.

BTW I'm developing for minimum sdk version of 16.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: create your own custom dialog

Comment: does your some code also contain `dialog.dismiss()` ?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016313/how-to-keep-an-alertdialog-open-after-button-onclick-is-fired

Answer (score 0):

If the code in onClick contains dialog.dismiss() then only dialog would get closed

Answer (score 0):

```
   String Strmessage="message";
            final AlertDialog.Builder alt_bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(SplashActivity.this);
            alt_bld.setMessage(Strmessage);
            alt_bld.setCancelable(true);
            alt_bld.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = alt_bld.create();           
            alt_bld.setMessage(Strmessage);
            alert.show();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions. I made a custom dialog and now it works just like i wanted.