# Does Dialog goes to Stack also? I want dialog above another dialog

Tags: android, dialog, stack, multiple-instances

I would like to know if dialogs go to stack, as Activities go..
Because I have now a dialog "A", and I can click on a button that opens a new dialog "B".. But if I close the dialog "B", there is no longer the dialog "A". 
And I dont want to create a new Dialog "A" I want to continue as the way I leave it..

The close button of "B" does nothing.. it has a null onClickListener:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(activity).setNegativeButton("Exit", null).show();
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Found the answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142308/android-dialog-keep-dialog-open-when-button-is-pressed

Thanks ;)

Comment: I think you should not show a `Dialog` on top of each other. Dialogs in Android are intended to be shown one at time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android you simply can't stack `Dialog` instances. You could achieve the same result managing the workflow yourself (A -> B -> A) but you have to save/restore A status yourself somehow.

So you could choice between:

1. switch to `DialogFragment` and use the fragment backstack and their instance management
2. subclass A and B from `Activity` and apply the `Theme.Dialog` to them

Comment: I am using DialogFragment and already got it working , thanks ;)