# How to retain alert dialog even when positive button is clicked?

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment

I have created an alert dialog with two buttons (using setPositiveButton and setNegativeButton APIs). But when I click on either of those buttons, the dialog is dismissed.

How to retain the dialog if **one** of the buttons (say the positive one) is clicked? Negative button should continue to exhibit normal behaviour.

Comment: can not get you, can you give some more

Comment: I got the answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142308/android-dialog-keep-dialog-open-when-button-is-pressed/6142413#6142413