# Validation on EditText in alertDialog

Tags: android, validation, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

I am trying to add empty field validations on `EditText` on `AlertDialog`. But even after field is empty error message is not getting displayed, instead `AlertDialog` is closing. But if conditions are working well as I'm not able to do post operations if any of the field is empty.

**Here is my Java Sample code:**

```
public class TourActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private LayoutInflater inflater;
private FloatingActionButton fab;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tour);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            inflater = TourActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
            View content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_add_new_trip, null);
            final EditText editEvent = (EditText) content.findViewById(R.id.edTxt_EventName);
            final EditText editStartDate = (EditText) content.findViewById(R.id.edTxt_EventSDate);


            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(TourActivity.this);
            builder.setView(content)
                    .setTitle("Add Event")
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                    editEvent.setError(null);
                                    editStartDate.setError(null);

                                    boolean cancel = false;
                                    View focusView = null;

                                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(editEvent.getText().toString()))) {
                                        editEvent.setError("Please Enter Event Name.");
                                        return;
                                    }

                                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(editStartDate.getText().toString())) {
                                        editStartDate.setError("Please Enter Event Start Date.");
                                        focusView = editStartDate;
                                        cancel = true;
                                    }


                                    if (cancel == true) {
                                        Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),
                                                "Event Unsuccessful.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                                .setActionTextColor(Color.RED)
                                                .show();
                                        focusView.requestFocus();
                                    } else {
                                        // Some action here
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton(cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: what is `edEvent` in `if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edEvent)) {` ?. How about commenting other validation first then check the first validation code.

Comment: Changed that line & corrected.

Answer (score 7):

This answer is compiled from [Android Dialog, keep dialog open when button is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142308/android-dialog-keep-dialog-open-when-button-is-pressed).

As written in [Dismissing Dialog API Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#DismissingADialog),

> When the user touches any of the action buttons created with an
>   AlertDialog.Builder, the system dismisses the dialog for you.

So you need to make a custom click listener for prevent the dialog being closed.

**[First Way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6142413/4758255)**
You can prevent the positive button from closing the dialog. You basically need to:

1. Create the dialog with DialogBuilder
2. show() the dialog
3. Find the buttons in the dialog shown and override their `onClickListener`

So, create a listener class:

```
class CustomListener implements View.OnClickListener {
  private final Dialog dialog;

  public CustomListener(Dialog dialog) {
    this.dialog = dialog;
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    // Do whatever you want here

    // If you want to close the dialog, uncomment the line below
    //dialog.dismiss();
  }
}
```

Then when showing the dialog use:

```
AlertDialog dialog = dialogBuilder.create();
dialog.show();
Button theButton = dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
theButton.setOnClickListener(new CustomListener(dialog));
```

Remember, you need to show the dialog otherwise the button will not be findable. Also, be sure to change **DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE** to whatever value you used to add the button. Also note that when adding the buttons in the `DialogBuilder` you will need to provide `onClickListeners` - you can not add the custom listener in there, though - the dialog will still dismiss if you do not override the listeners after `show()` is called.

**[Second Way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15619411/4758255)**

Here is an example of the same approach using an anonymous class instead so it is all in one stream of code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
builder.setMessage("Test for preventing dialog close");
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();

//Overriding the handler immediately after show is probably a better approach than OnShowListener as described below
dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {            
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
       boolean wantToCloseDialog = false;

       //Do stuff, possibly set wantToCloseDialog to true then...
       if(wantToCloseDialog)
          dismiss();
       //else dialog stays open. Make sure you have an obvious way to close the dialog especially if you set cancellable to false.
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how to validate input password inside AlertDialog.

Make sure you have created an individual xml layout file for the password which has only one component/view that is `EditText` to get the password from the user.

After creating a layout for input password, we will inflate the layout with Dialog as to set our custom view to the AlertDialog.

```
Inflater inflater = new Inflater(this);
View myPasswordView = inflater.inflate(R.xml.my_custom_password_layout);

AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Password");
//alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Enter password to open Application.");
alertDialogBuilder.setView(myPasswordView);

alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                // Do not use this place as we are overriding this button later in the cade.
            }
        }); alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Cancel", 
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener({
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                // Dismiss dialog and close activity if appropriated, do not use this (cancel) button at all. 
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
alertDialog.show();
// Overriding the that button here immediatly handle the user's activity.
alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
      {            
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v)
          {
              Boolean isError = false;
              //Do your job here. For example we are checking the input password.
              final EditText txtPassword = myPasswordView.findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);
              String password = txtPassword.getText().toString().trim();
              Boolean isError = true;

              // Check password if not empty. You can add another IF statement to do your logic for password validation.
              if(password.isEmpty()) {
                  isError = true;
                  txtPassword.setError("Password cannot be empty");
              }
              if(password.equals("1234") {
                  // You password is correct. 
                  isError = false;
                  txtPassword.setError(null);
              }
              if(!isError)
                  dialog.dismiss();
              // Otherwise the dialog will stay open.
          }
      });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try like this:

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edEvent)) {
    editEvent.setError("Please Enter Event Name.");
    editEvent.requestFocus();
    return;
}
```