# Show confirmation dialog in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I'm converting my Android application to use fragments. Previously, I had an activity that is now a fragment. Hence, this code can no longer be used:

```
showDialog(CONFIRM_ID);
// ...
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    // Create the confirmation dialog...
}
```

From within the `Fragment` object, I need to show a confirmation dialog that after confirmation throws me back to the object for status update.

E.g.

1. Inside fragment X.
2. Show confirmation dialog.
3. If "yes" update UI for X.

How can I accomplish this? Please provide working sample code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply create your dialogs (AlertDialog) using the code as shown here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
       .setCancelable(false)
       .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                MyActivity.this.finish();
           }
       })
       .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
           }
       });
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

If you need to create dialogs with buttons that do not immediately dismiss the dialog itself you can see my answer here: [How to prevent a dialog from closing when a button is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620444/android-how-to-prevent-dialog-closed-or-remain-dialog-when-button-is-clicked/9523257#9523257)

Comment: Thanks. This will suffice! (But I suspect the best solution is to use `DialogFragment` and somehow propagate the result back to the originating fragment.)

Answer (score 0):

```
         AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());       
         builder.setTitle("Your Title");
         builder.setMessage("Your Dialog Message");
         builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                  //TODO
                  dialog.dismiss();
             }
         });
         builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                  //TODO
                  dialog.dismiss();
             }
         });
         AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
         dialog.show();
```