# Prevent AlertDialog from closing

Tags: java, android

I have a custom AlertDialog with a bunch of checkboxes. I want to prevent the AlertDialog from closing if none of the checkboxes are selected. Is this possible?

I know I can close momentarily and re-open it, but I would rather not do this as I have some code within the setPositiveButton which I do not want to repeat.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I want to prevent the AlertDialog from closing
```

**Already Posted [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7636468/1278196) on SO**

OR

Create `Custom Dialog` to solve the issue.

Comment: I already have setCancelable to false. My problem is that I want to stop it from closing when the PositiveButton is pressed if the none of the checkboxes are ticked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using a custom view, so disable the OK/Cancel buttons at the bottom.  Next you'll need to disable the back button:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {}
```

The only thing left is to make sure your dialog fills the screen.  If the user clicks beside the box on the parent view the dialog will close.