# Avoiding dismissing my dialog when the neutral button is pressed

Tags: android, dialog, dismiss

In the `onCreateDialog()` method of my custom dialog, i set, using the builder, the positive, cancel and neutral button listeners.

I want to use the neutral button to reset the dialog interface controls and do not want it to dismiss the dialog when the user press it.

How can i do this?

Ps.
My custom dialog is based on the FireMissilesDialogFragment example of the android developer guide. I setup the neutral button in the same way i setup the ok and cancel buttons. But i do not know how to prevent dialog dismission when the neutral button is pressed.

Comment: Can you show the code for the button's `onClick()`?

Comment: Look at [Tom Bollwitt's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620444/how-to-prevent-a-dialog-from-closing-when-a-button-is-clicked)

Comment: Sajmon thanks! That was the right direction.