# Eclipse detect error on the implementation of setOnShowListener

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I want to set my setOnShowListener() method to prevent dialog from closing, so I write something like this,

```
public Dialog update_pop_up()
{
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(UgJadwal.this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = UgJadwal.this.getLayoutInflater();
    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.updatepopup, null);
    builder.setView(dialogView);
    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.update);
    builder.setTitle("Update schedule");

    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.update, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
        {

        }
    });

    builder.setNeutralButton(R.string.retrieve, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
        {

        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, null);
    return builder.create();

    builder.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog)
        {
            Button retrieve = builder.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL);
            retrieve.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    //do nothing;
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

At least there are two error prompted by eclipse, the first one is on the `setOnShowListener` that say "The method setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener(){}) is undefined for the type AlertDialog.Builder" and the other one is on the `builder.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL)` that say "The method getButton(int) is undefined for the type AlertDialog.Builder". I just wonder why it raises errors becuase I have do it right I think. Does everyone have an idea to fix it, thanks.

[UPDATE!!]
Thanks everybody for your help. This is my final methoD on `setOnShowListener()`

```
dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog)
        {
            Button retrieve = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL);
            retrieve.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    datasource.opentoread();
                    String[] hari = datasource.fetchDaily(ids.getText().toString());
                    datasource.close();
                    day.setText(String.valueOf(hari[0]));
                    subject.setText(String.valueOf(hari[1]));
                    time.setText(String.valueOf(hari[2]));
                    location.setText(String.valueOf(hari[3]));
                    lecture.setText(String.valueOf(hari[4]));
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Retrieve success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return dialog;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the first one is on the setOnShowListener that say "The method setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener(){}) is undefined for the type AlertDialog.Builder"

There are two reasons why you'll get an error with this:

```
builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, null);
return builder.create();

builder.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() ...
```

1. You will never reach any code after calling `return`.
2. [`setOnShowListener()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setOnShowListener%28android.content.DialogInterface.OnShowListener%29) is a method in AlertDialog, not AlertDialog.Builder.

---

> that say "The method getButton(int) is undefined for the type AlertDialog.Builder"

This is the same problem, [`getButton()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#getButton%28int%29) is a method in AlertDialog, not AlertDialog.Builder.

---

Try something like this:

```
...
builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, null);

final AlertDialog dlg = builder.create();
dlg.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog)
    {
        Button retrieve = dlg.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL);
        // Changed this   ^^^
        retrieve.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                //do nothing;
            }
        });
    }
});
return dlg;
```

Comment: well thanks, I already check your method, it works for the `setOnShowListener()` ut in the `dialog.getButton()` it still make an error, it says `The method getButton(int) is undefined for the type DialogInterface` do you have any other idea?

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice that the parameter for `onShow()` was _also_ named `dialog`, so I changed the other variable's name now there's no conflict.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [AlertDialog.Builder documentation](http://android.app.AlertDialog.Builder), `setOnShowListener` is not a valid method of `AlertDialog.Builder`. However, it is a valid method of `AlertDialog`, which is the return type for `builder.create()`. Similarly for `getButton` which is actually a method of `AlertDialog`. Therefore your code should be:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
alertDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog)
    {
        Button retrieve = alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL);
        retrieve.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                //do nothing;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: The `DialogInterface dialog` in `onShow` will hide the `AlertDialog dialog` you have defined outside....

Answer (score 0):

Or instead of creating an AlertDialog, you could just use a standard Dialog and then dismiss it when you want or listen to when the user closes the dialog. This would be a better alternative instead of using the default behavior of a button click closing the Dialog  (AlertDialog).