# AlertDialog Button pressed Cancellation

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

What I need is to show message but do nothing. I've tried with "break" and "return true/false". Any suggestion? And my code is:

```
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    if(chosenCat.size() < 2){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Min 2 categories to compare.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //...needs to abort OK button like nothing pressed
    } else {
        //...do some stuff
}
}
});
```

Comment: What does "I need is cancellation of pressed button" mean?

Comment: sorry bad English :D
When OK clicked I need to do nothing in first case. Not even close dialog.

Comment: you want to click twice on the ok button before to close the dialog?

Comment: do nothing if(chosenCat.size() < 2) just Toast... Do not close AlertDialog!

Comment: With your current code, what happens if choseCat.size() is less than two? Given your current structure, the only thing executed should be the Toast statement.

Comment: @Phil Applegate: Yes, that is right but it closes dialog but I want to stay opened.

Comment: See my updated answer to keep a dialog box open after a button has been pressed.

Answer (score 0):

To keep a dialog open after one of the buttons has been pressed please see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7636468/1344221).

You can add an onShowListener to the AlertDialog where you can then override the onClickListener of the button.

```
final AlertDialog d = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        .setView(v)
        .setTitle(R.string.my_title)
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                new Dialog.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int which) {
                        //Do nothing here. We override the onclick
                    }
                })
        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)
        .create();

d.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {

    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {

        Button b = d.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO Do something

                //Dismiss once everything is OK.
                d.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Code reproduced from above link for reference.

Comment: @Arnes What is stopping you from overriding?

Answer (score 0):

try to use `dialog.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON1).setEnabled(false);`

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
        if(chosenCat.size() < 2){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Min 2 categories to compare.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
}
});
```

After this create create dialog like the following

```
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

After called `show()`
check your condition

```
if(chosenCat.size() < 2){
    dialog.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score -1):

What is your exact requirement. From the condition:

```
    if(chosenCat.size() < 2){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Min 2 categories to compare.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

from the above condition I understand you are trying to cancel the OK button only in case there are less selected options than the minimum.

Rather than cancel, why don't you set "isEnabled()" param of the OK button to false. and if and only if there are minimum selections the OK button is visible. Say:

```
if(chosenCat.size()<2){
   button1.isEnabled()="false";
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Select minimum 2 options", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
else {
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new OnClickListener() 
{
       //DO SOMETHING
 }
 });
```