# setOnShowListener () not working in DialogPreference

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

I am implementing a `DialogPreference` in a class. I want that when the positive button of the dialog is clicked, the dialog should not dismiss. I am using the logic from [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7636468/2486731)

Insided the class I use:

```
protected void onPrepareDialogBuilder(Builder builder) {
    super.onPrepareDialogBuilder(builder);

    final AlertDialog d = builder.create();

    d.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {

        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {

            Toast.makeText(mContext, "inside", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Button b = d.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // TODO Do something

                    // Dismiss once everything is OK.
                    d.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

But when I open the dialog, I do not see the `Toast`,and the dialog closes. So how is my implementation of [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7636468/2486731) wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your situation is a bit different. You can't call "builder.create()" in onPrepareDialogBuilder method. See API reference [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/DialogPreference.html#onPrepareDialogBuilder%28android.app.AlertDialog.Builder%29).

Unfortunately this means that you don't have access to dialog object and you can't set onShowListener. Try extending Preference class and build your dialog there.

Answer (score -1):

There is a hack you can apply (ugly but will work). Try the following override:

```
@Override
protected View onCreateDialogView() {
    View view = super.onCreateDialogView();

    view.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(new View.OnAttachStateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onViewAttachedToWindow(View view) {
            Button b = d.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // TODO Do something

                    // Dismiss once everything is OK.
                    d.dismiss();
                }
            });            }

        @Override
        public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(View view) {

        }
    });

    return view;
}
```