# Android: Is it possible not to close the AlertDialog.Builder automatically?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have an `alertDialogBuilder` of type `AlertDialog.Builder`. This has two buttons, one positive and another one negative. When the positive button is clicked, I have a condition check and if  it is successful, only then the `alertDialogBuilder` should be closed else the android app should keep displaying it. Is this possible?

Current code

```
EditText editText;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("test");
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("testMessage");
    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);                        
    editText = new EditText(this);
    editText.setText("hi");
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(editText);
    editText.requestFocus();

    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", dialogLinstener);
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Save", dialogLinstener);

    alertDialogBuilder.show();
}

private DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogLinstener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {            
        if(which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE) {

            String str = editText.getText().toString();
            if(!str.equals("hi")) {

                               // do something..

            } else {

                               // do something else..

            }
        } else if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE) {
            //do nothing.
        }

        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (imm != null)
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);

        return;
    }
};
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620444/how-to-prevent-a-dialog-from-closing-when-a-button-is-clicked

Answer (score 1):

Keep a reference to the `AlertDialog` that the `AlertDialog.Builder` creates. You can then show or dismiss the `AlertDialog` as you please.

```
AlertDialog dialog =  alertDialogBuilder.create(); 
dialog.show();
```

and then somewhere else:

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by **not to close the AlertDialog.Builder automatically** that is should not close when clicked outside then you can do the following :-

```
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

If you just want to only close the dialog when a condition is met then keep a reference to `AlertDialog` that the `AlertDialog.Builder` creates as @Ascorbin correctly said then in your condition

```
if(condition == true){
//code
dialog.dismiss();
}
```

This way dialog will only close if condition is met.

Comment: hey thanks for the reply, but this is not what I meant.

Comment: @Shobhit Then what you really mean?