# Dialog don't close with "cancelable = true"

Tags: android, android-dialog

I have a dialog, which is cancelable, if I click beside of my dialog. But before closing the dialog, I want to check a field and if the check is negative, then the dialog should not close. I thought, that I could do that, if I override the onDismiss() method, but it doesn't work.

Which method I have to override to do the check and decide, if the dialog should close or stay open?
Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

To keep dialog open when click the button, you must override the DialogInterface.OnShowListener.
Check the answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620444/how-to-prevent-a-dialog-from-closing-when-a-button-is-clicked).
You can use AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE to get the negative button, then override the onClickListener yourself to prevent dialog dismissing.

Comment: I don't have a button in my dialog to close it. I'm using a DialogFragment, which should close, if i click beside of the dialog. So i need to override the method, which is calling dismiss(), if i click beside of my dialog.

Comment: Oh...sorry, I assumed you use the AlertDialog. orz

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the best solution but you should be able to override the `cancel` method and call super upon you validation.

```
@Override
public void cancel() {
    if (YOUR_LOGIC) {
       super.cancel();
    }

    // do nothing
}
```