# Do NOTHING when clicking AlertDialog.PossitiveButton

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-dialog

I have an `AlertDialog` with an `EditText` inside it:

```
final EditText et = new EditText(getActivity());
AlertDialog.Builder myDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
myDialog.setTitle("My Title").setView(et);
myDialog.setPositiveButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        if(et.getText().toString() != ""){
            //Do funny things
        }
    }
});
myDialog.setNegativeButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    }
});
```

My objective is do nothing if the `EditText` is empty, with nothing i mean nothing. But there are 2 problems:

1. When click on `setPositiveButton`, the dialog is closed even if the `onClick` method is empty.
2. If `EditText` is empty i don't know which ASCII character should I match in the if condition. I mean:

   ```
   vNombre.getText().toString() == null;
   vNombre.getText().toString() == " ";
   vNombre.getText().toString() == "";
   ```

This 3 statements return false so I don't know with what I should compare `et.getText().toString()`

Is there any solution to problem 1 without add custom button to the view of the dialog?

Any ideas for problem 2?

Comment: You cannot compare strings with `==` operator. In this particular case, I would use `TextUtils.isEmpty(et.getText().toString());`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620444/how-to-prevent-a-dialog-from-closing-when-a-button-is-clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use `equals("")` instead of `==`

```
 if(!et.getText().toString().equals("")
{
                   //Do funny things
  }
```

You can read [Java String Compare Example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/lang/string/java-string-compare-example/)

> [What's the difference between ".equals" and "=="?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643067/whats-the-difference-between-equals-and)

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use the below code for checking if a `String` is empty instead of the above.

```
if  (!TextUtils.isEmpty(et.getText().toString())) {

}
```

To not close the dialog when the positive button is clicked you would need to make a custom `Dialog` there is plenty of SO questions/answers on this already. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24244096/stop-alertdialog-from-closing-on-positive-button-click).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String gettext = et.getText().toString();

if(!gettext.contentEquals("")){
       //do funny things
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Always check for length of string for checking empty.

```
int length = ed.getText().toString().trim().length();
if(length > 0)
{
   //do your work here
}
```