# Stop closing AlertDialog after click on positive button in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog

title saying what I need

I need to AlertDialog will not close after I click on positive button because I need show a message in that AlertDialog when user click on positive button

a have found this [Stop AlertDialog from closing on positive button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24244096/stop-alertdialog-from-closing-on-positive-button-click) but I can't use it in Kotlin

```
  alertDialog.setPositiveButton("ok"){ dialogInterface, i ->
        if(myET.text.toString().length !in 10..100){
            myET.error = "text size not in the range"
            //here must not close
        }else{
            myfunction()
            // only here must close
        }
  }
```

Comment: Onclick performs an action that you defined. After performing that action dialog box has to closed, you can show your message or another dialog box on Ok button clicked. When the ok button is clicked then another dialog or message you defined will prompt. hope it clears now

Answer (score 0):

Use an AlertDilaog with a custom view.

```
val dialogBuilder: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    val inflater = this.layoutInflater
    val dialogView: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_layout, null)
    dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView)

    val positiveButton =
        dialogView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.positive_button) as EditText

    val alertDialog: AlertDialog = dialogBuilder.create()
    alertDialog.show()
    
    positiveButton.setOnClickListener { 
        //do whatever you have to do here

        //dismiss dialog when done
        alertDialog.dismiss()
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but i positive button that defined in alter dialog not custom button

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope it works

```
 final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
    .setView(v)
    .setTitle(R.string.my_title)
    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null) 
    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)
    .create();

 dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {

@Override
public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {

    Button button = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO Do something

            //Dismiss once everything is OK.
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
});
dialog.show();
```

Comment: i will get this error after clicking on "ok" button
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: I have made some changes in my code can you try this code @احمدمحمودی

Comment: what I should send to ".setView()" ?

Comment: I don't wanna to change my alter dialog I just wanna to doing something that when my if is run, alter dialog not close and show my message and user do it again