# Android : use the explorer?

Tags: android, file, explorer

I want to allow the user to choose a file in the explorer. (Specifically a PDF file only)

I searched a little, but I don't arrive to find something in the developer doc Android.

There is nothing to do it easily ?

For example, I want something like GMAIL uses when the user wants to join a file to a mail.

Thx for help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadfully, you have to write an fileexplorer yourself or us an external fileexplorer (which isn't always present). As I've got the same problem the last days, this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25724970/3960095. It's a filebrowser in a Fragment. Feel free to use it :)

Comment: don't forget to change FILE_SUFFIX(at the beginning of class FileAdapter) to ".pdf" for only showing pdf-files. You'll also need two pictures ic_folder and ic_file in your drawable-XXX-Folder, which should be the picture for a Folder and a File...

Comment: Yes, i did it :) Thanks a lot guys for your share and help :)

Comment: Do you have an idea to restrict folders to show ? Because they are a lot of folders which are useless.

Comment: how can I have an access to the download folder ?

Comment: The download folder should be Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download", i think. I forgot about the empty folders, because the phone I'm using here is rooted. I'd suggest to set the root-Directory to the SDcard (change isBaseDir(), SDcard should be Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()) or maybe check if a Directory is empty before adding it to the adapter.

Comment: mhh, I understand what you're saying, but, sincerily, currently, i don't understand exactly how your code works ^^

Comment: I tried to just set File dirTest = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); but, I've again a lots of folder empty, and no one which contains my pdf downloaded.

Comment: There is a problem but i don't find where :( I haven't file in my sdcare or storage, and in reality there are more folders with pdf files.

Comment: That's odd. Sorry, but I can't help you before monday, important project here. You want to show only pdf-files, starting directory should be the download-folder and empty files should not be shown, right? I'll post working code on Monday...

Comment: I don't understand why, but it seems there is a problem here :

            if (folder.listFiles() != null && folder.listFiles().length > 0){
             Log.e("ok file", "ok"  + folder.listFiles().length); 
                fileList = new ArrayList<File>(Arrays.asList(folder.listFiles()));
            }else{
                fileList = new ArrayList<File>();
            }

It returns always null, when I set the main path to Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)

(and I'm sure, there are few pdf files)