# How to disable alert dialog close, if editText inside Alert dialog is empty

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

I am trying to disable alert dialog close if TextView is Empty,I gone through few posts but non of them are custom Alert Dialog.
How to solve this. Thanks in Advance
**Here is my code sample Custom Alert Dialog code**

```
     protected void showInputDialog() {

    // get prompts.xml view
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(Nav_Settings.this);
    View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_settings_change_password, null);
    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Nav_Settings.this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);
    alertDialogBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.icon_secret);

    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("CHANGE PASSWORD");

    final EditText currentPassword = (EditText) promptView.findViewById(R.id.etCurrentPassword);
    final EditText newPassword = (EditText) promptView.findViewById(R.id.etNewPassword);
    final EditText confirmNewPassword = (EditText) promptView.findViewById(R.id.etConfirmNewPassword);

    // setup a dialog window
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Update Password", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(currentPassword.getText().toString().trim())) {
                currentPassword.setError("should not be empty");
            } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newPassword.getText().toString().trim())) {
                newPassword.setError("should not be empty");
            } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(confirmNewPassword.getText().toString().trim())) {
                confirmNewPassword.setError("should not be empty");
            } else if (newPassword.getText().toString().trim() != confirmNewPassword.getText().toString().trim()) {
                confirmNewPassword.setError("new password not matching");
            } else if (currentPassword == newPassword) {
                newPassword.setError("new password should not be current password");
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), currentPassword.getText().toString() + "\n" + newPassword.getText().toString() + "\n" + confirmNewPassword.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    }).setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    // create an alert dialog
    AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alert.show();
    alert.getButton(alert.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
    alert.getButton(alert.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
    Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "fonts/RobotoCondensed-Bold.ttf");
    alert.getButton(alert.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTypeface(face);
    alert.getButton(alert.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTypeface(face);
}
```

Comment: did you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26086848/android-dont-dismiss-alertdialog-after-clicking-positivebutton)

Comment: Check my answer now.

Comment: Thankyou all, I followed @kishire Jethava suggestion, worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Initially set it as disabled:

```
Button button = alert.getButton(alert.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
button.setEnabled(false);
alert.setCancelable(false);
```

Add a TextWhatcher on your password EditText:

```
currentPassword.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(currentPassword.getText().toString().trim())){
                button.setEnabled(false);
                alert.setCancelable(false);
            } else{
                button.setEnabled(true);
                alert.setCancelable(true);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
```

Basically, each time the user changing the text in the EditText you can check if it's empty or not & enable/ disable the Cancel button accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a boolean at the top of the method and make it true only when all the validations are cleared

```
protected void showInputDialog() {

// get prompts.xml view
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(Nav_Settings.this);
View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_settings_change_password, null);
final boolean isCloseValid = false; // THIS BOOLEAN
final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Nav_Settings.this);
alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);
alertDialogBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.icon_secret);

alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("CHANGE PASSWORD");

final EditText currentPassword = (EditText) promptView.findViewById(R.id.etCurrentPassword);
final EditText newPassword = (EditText) promptView.findViewById(R.id.etNewPassword);
final EditText confirmNewPassword = (EditText) promptView.findViewById(R.id.etConfirmNewPassword);

// setup a dialog window
alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Update Password", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(currentPassword.getText().toString().trim())) {
            currentPassword.setError("should not be empty");
isValidClose = false // VALIDATION FALSE
        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newPassword.getText().toString().trim())) {
            newPassword.setError("should not be empty");
isValidClose = false // VALIDATION FALSE
        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(confirmNewPassword.getText().toString().trim())) {
            confirmNewPassword.setError("should not be empty");
isValidClose = false // VALIDATION FALSE
        } else if (newPassword.getText().toString().trim() != confirmNewPassword.getText().toString().trim()) {
            confirmNewPassword.setError("new password not matching");
isValidClose = false // VALIDATION FALSE
        } else if (currentPassword == newPassword) {
            newPassword.setError("new password should not be current password");
isValidClose = false // VALIDATION FALSE
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), currentPassword.getText().toString() + "\n" + newPassword.getText().toString() + "\n" + confirmNewPassword.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
isValidClose = true; // MAKE TRUE HERE 

        }
    }
}).setNegativeButton("Cancel",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
             if(isValidClose){ // if validations is cleared
               dialog.cancel();
              }
            }
        });

// create an alert dialog
AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
alert.show();
alert.getButton(alert.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
alert.getButton(alert.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
        "fonts/RobotoCondensed-Bold.ttf");
alert.getButton(alert.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTypeface(face);
alert.getButton(alert.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTypeface(face);
```

}