# Is it possible to change the behaviour of a dialog button after the dialog has been created?

Tags: android, android-dialog

I am preparing a login dialog that can change to a register dialog.

It has a custom view and contains a clickable text view that I use to switch between the register display and login display.

When a user clicks it I change the title of the dialog and I display or vanish the input box for retyping the password.

However, I can't change the text or the `OnClick` function of the positive button.

the `setPositiveButton` method only exists for `DialogBuilder` but not for the dialog itself.

Do I have to rebuild the entire dialog or is there a way to change the button "on the fly"?

Comment: This answer has some sample code to add to answer below - http://stackoverflow.com/q/2620444/1256219

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have created your dialog, you can access the buttons with help of this:

```
dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON1) //BUTTON1 is positive button
```

With this you can modify the text of the button.