# How to check value before dismiss a dialog?

Tags: android

I want to show a dialog. When click outside the dialog , i want dialog to get dismiss. But before dismissing a dialog, i want to check for a condition, if correct then dismiss the dialog, else if value is incorrect don't dismiss it.

Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: Share the relevant code please

Comment: Alert dialog? Please be specific and show code.

Comment: There is surely a way to make this work but I will highly recommend you to use negative and positive button on your dialog box and setCancelable(false) (only if your app can not proceed further without the value entered by user) on it.

Comment: Try to implement this interface : DialogInterface.OnDismissListener

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620444/how-to-prevent-a-dialog-from-closing-when-a-button-is-clicked

Answer (score 1):

Keep `setCancelabe(false);` until the value in the `EditText` is not correct. use `TextWatcher`to check value, and whenever your value is correct then set `setCancelabe(true);`

Answer (score 0):

You can check the value when inputting with `TextWatcher`. Or set custom onClickListener to the positive button.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder();

// build dialog

AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener(){

    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface){


        ((AlertDialog)dialogInterface).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)
                                      .setOnClickListener(// check value here)


    }
}

dialog.show();
```

remember to invoke `dialogInterface.dismiss()` when you ready to dismiss it.