# Unable to setError inside a Dialog that closes by itself

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

As the title, I'm facing issues while setting an error inside `EditText mEditText`.

```
 private AlertDialog.Builder buildDialog(String mailString)
  {
    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder =
      new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);

    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Insert mail");
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("email");
    // Set an EditText view to get user input
    mMailEditText = new EditText(LoginActivity.this);
    if (mailString != null)
      mMailEditText.setText(mailString);
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(mMailEditText);
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(
      "Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
      {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
        {
          String email = mMailEditText.getText().toString();
          if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && !isEmailValid(email))
          {
             mMailEditText.setError(getString(
                R.string.activity_login_error_invalid_email));
          }
          else
          {
            attemptLoginOrRegister(UserTasks.REGISTER, email);
          }
        }
      });
    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(
      "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
      {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
        {
          dialog.cancel();
        }
      });

    mAlertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    return alertDialogBuilder;
  }

  private void setListeners()
  {
    mRegisterButton.setOnClickListener(
      new View.OnClickListener()
      {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
          buildDialog(null).show();
        }
      });
  }
```

`setListeners()` get always called from `onCreate`, while `buildDialog` is called when the user perfroms a click on the register button.
Debugging the app, the line containing `mMailEditText.setError()` is correctly executed if the email isn't valid, but the error message isn't displayed and the dialog simply closes.
What is wrong with my approach?

EDIT: if you want, [here](http://pastebin.com/678etyRH) is a simplified version of the class code that doesn't require any external library. I've also added [layout](http://pastebin.com/kyXgU5YN) and [strings](http://pastebin.com/iSAfr7Ht) files.

Comment: are u sure mMailEditText.setError( is called?

Comment: sure, it always get called when the condition is true.

Comment: use getResources().getString(R.string.error_invalid_email);

Comment: I've also tried to split the `getString()` part from the `setError()` part; the string is correctly retrieved and the error correctly assigned to the `EditText`. Simply, it doesn't show anything and the dialog get closed @diva

Comment: @diva it doesn't work even using `getResources()`. Btw, pretty new to chats, I'll be here in a few moments

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent a dialog from closing when a button is clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620444/how-to-prevent-a-dialog-from-closing-when-a-button-is-clicked)

Answer (score 4):

You have gone for the right approach although you need to change your code.
Please take a look at the following code:

```
   View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);

   final EditText editTextEmail = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editCategory);

   final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this)
            .setView(view)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.str_ok, null)
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.str_cancel, null)
            .create();

    alertDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {

            Button buttonPositive = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            buttonPositive.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                 // Do whatever you want when positive button is clicked
            });

            Button buttonNegative = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
            buttonNegative.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
// Do whatever you want when negative button is clicked
                }
            });
        }
    });

    alertDialog.show();
```

Create an XML layout including the `EditText` you want. Inflate the layout in a view and pass that view in `setView` method of `AlertDialog`'s instance. 
Simply override `setOnShowListener` using `AlertDialog`'s instance.
Thereafter, retrieve the positive and negative buttons as shown above.
That's it.