# Require input from dialog

Tags: android

In my dialog the user is required to input a name to save a file. If it's not entered a toast should appear saying that a file name is required and the dialog should remain. How to implement this in the positive button click listener and **prevent the dialog from closing** if the file name isn't specified? Here's the listener:

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
```

Comment: Check this out

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620444/how-to-prevent-a-dialog-from-closing-when-a-button-is-clicked

I had referred to this once