# Continue displaying AlertDialog if entered wrong password

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I've successfully displayed an `EditText` in the `AlertDialog`. When entered text in the edit field, it is compared with a custom text. If the entered text doesn't match, the `AlertDilaog` should continue to show but currently the dialog is closing Positive Button is clicked, even if a wrong password was entered.

Do you guys have a solution for this?

UPDATED:
Here is the code

```
builder.setView(v)
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    EditText enteredPassword = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.enteredPassword);
                    if (enteredPassword.getText().toString().trim().equals(correctPassword.trim()) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "User Entered Right Answer");
                      } else {
                        Log.i(TAG, "User Entered Wrong Answer");
                        // Continue showing the dialog if Wrong Answer is entered
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter a proper answer", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Do you have a code for this?

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620444/how-to-prevent-a-dialog-from-closing-when-a-button-is-clicked

Comment: alertDialog is dismissed when Positive button or negative button is clicked, that is why its called an AlertDialog, instead of alert dialog why not use dialog, you can set a layout to the dialog using the setContentView button, http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/ has an example on creating custom dialogs

Comment: @Rohit5k2 I've pasted the code. Look into it.

Comment: @DivyaNagrath I've pasted the code. Look into it.

Comment: @SrikarReddy: Please see my answer.

Comment: @Bhargav I haven't tried your answer yet, once I tried I'll let you know. I'm having a feeling that your suggestion will sure work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. You basically need to:

1. Create the dialog with DialogBuilder
2. show() the dialog
3. Find the buttons in the dialog shown and override their onClickListener

So, create a listener class:

```
class CustomListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    private final Dialog dialog;
    public CustomListener(Dialog dialog) {
        this.dialog = dialog;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // Do whatever you want here

        // If tou want to close the dialog, uncomment the line below
        //dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Then when showing the dialog use:

```
AlertDialog dialog = dialogBuilder.create();
dialog.show();
Button theButton = dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
theButton.setOnClickListener(new CustomListener(dialog));
```

Remember, you need to show the dialog otherwise the button will not be findeable. Also, be sure to change `DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE` to whatever value you used to add the button. Also note that when adding the buttons in the `DialogBuilder` you will need to provide `onClickListeners` - you cannot add the custom listener in there, though - the dialog will still dismiss if you do not override the listeners after `show()` is called.

Comment: When the positive button is clicked, whether if condition or else condition is executed, the alert dialog is getting dismissed. `dialog.dismiss()` is currently irrelevant. Even then, I've added your suggestion and alert dialog is closing when else condition is executed.

Comment: then you need to use custom listener. Check my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dialog.dismiss();` in your condition .

**FYI**

Use  **dialog.dismiss(); instead dialog.cancel();**

Finally, Like this way

```
if (enteredPassword.getText().toString().trim().equals(correctPassword.getText().toString().trim()) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "User Entered Right Answer");
                      dialog.dismiss();
                  } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "User Entered Wrong Answer");
                    // Continue showing the dialog if Wrong Answer is entered
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter a proper answer", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
```

Please have a look

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#dismiss()

Comment: Even if I use the `dialog.dismiss()` inside the if loop, whenever the else condition is executed, the dialog box is still getting closed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {
            if(is text correct)
            {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as **Part 1** and use **Part 2** just after you show the dialog

**Part 1**

```
builder.setView(v)
       .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               // Don't do anything here. Will override it later     
           }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
```

**Part 2**

```
dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
  {            
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v)
      {
          EditText enteredPassword = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.enteredPassword);
          if (enteredPassword.getText().toString().trim().equals(correctPassword.getText().toString().trim()) {
              Log.i(TAG, "User Entered Right Answer");
              disalog.dismiss();
          } else {
              Log.i(TAG, "User Entered Wrong Answer");
              // Continue showing the dialog if Wrong Answer is entered
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter a proper answer", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
      }
  });
```