# If string does not contain certain words be unable leave dialog

Tags: android, dialog, alert, cancellation

I want my code to check if what is written in my dialog contains a certain string and if not to be unable to close the dialog. Now when I press the okay button the dialog disappears despite the fact the toast appears, so I guess I have done something wrong with `setCancelable`

```
             protected void showInputDialog() {
    // get prompts.xml view
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
    View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.url, null);

    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this, AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK);
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);

    final EditText editText = (EditText) promptView.findViewById(R.id.Button01);

    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Enter URL");
   // alertDialogBuilder.setCustomTitle("Enter URL");
   // alertDialogBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);

    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);

    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("DONE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            String value = editText.getText().toString();

            if (value.contains("www.facebook.com/")) {
                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You didn't enter the Name",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               // alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You didn't enter the Name",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
            }
        }
    });
    // create an alert dialog
    AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

Any suggestions how to fix that?

**edit:**
I have posted the whole function although I don't think it will help you

Comment: you have posted not enough code, post the whole function which contains this code snippet?

Comment: @Derek Fung I posted the whole code please take a look

Answer (score 1):

u can use `onShowListener`

```
dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {

    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {

        Button okBtn = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        okBtn .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (value.contains("www.stackoverflow.com/")) {
                   //do stuff
                   d.dismiss();         
                   }
                   else
                   {
                         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You didn't enter the Name                   correctly",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
                       //Don't put dismiss() here 
                   }

            }
        });
    }
});
```

based on what i understood from your question this should work

Comment: My problem is that the `alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);` doen't work which means the dialog dismisses when it shouldn't

Answer (score 1):

It is not related to `setCancelable`, which only disallow cancel by user, but not disable cancel by code.

By default, AlertDialog will close on any button click, but there is a workaround.

Actually @mothana is talking about the same workaround, I try to put it together with your code.

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this, AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK);
alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);

final EditText editText = (EditText) promptView.findViewById(R.id.Button01);

alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Enter URL");

alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);

alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("DONE", null); //part of the workaround
// create an alert dialog
final AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();

// workaround
alert.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {

    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {

        Button okBtn = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        okBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (value.contains("www.stackoverflow.com/")) {
                   //you code here
                   alert.dismiss();         
                }
                else
                {
                     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You didn't enter the Name",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     //Don't put dismiss() here 
                }

            }
        });
    }
});
alert.show();
```

You can check the reference here
[How to prevent a dialog from closing when a button is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620444/how-to-prevent-a-dialog-from-closing-when-a-button-is-clicked)