# why AlertDialog of android.support.v7.app.alertdialog class auto cancelled? i am not talking about android.app.AlertDialog class dialogue

Tags: android, dialog, android-support-library, android-alertdialog, android-appcompat

I have Created a dialogue using android.support.v7.app.alertdialog class. here is my code

```
   final AlertDialog.Builder myAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);
    myAlertDialog.setTitle("Enter Text");
    final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    input.setLayoutParams(lp);
    myAlertDialog.setView(input);
    myAlertDialog.setCancelable(false);
    myAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            if (input.getText().toString().length() != 0) {
                myAlertDialog.setCancelable(true);
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,SelectCatDialogue.class).putExtra("text",input.getText().toString()));
            } else {
                myAlertDialog.setCancelable(false);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please Enter Text",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    myAlertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            myAlertDialog.setCancelable(true);
        }
    });
    myAlertDialog.show();
```

now this dialog auto cancelled when i click on either positive or negative button but i need it should only cancelled on negative button not on positive button

Comment: make `setCancelable` false on `setPositiveButton` and true on `setNegativeButton`

Comment: i have edit my code according to your suggestion but still not work @Mohit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent a dialog from closing when a button is clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620444/how-to-prevent-a-dialog-from-closing-when-a-button-is-clicked)

Comment: @MikeM. dear i am talking about  AlertDialog of android.support.v7.app.alertdialog class dialoog not simple app.alertdialog

Comment: It's the same method for the appcompat Dialog.

Comment: @MikeM. android.support.v7.app.alertdialog class object don't have dismiss and cancel methods . i tried alot here is the official documentaion
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html

Comment: "android.support.v7.app.alertdialog class object don't have dismiss and cancel methods ." - Yes it does. It's a descendent of the [`Dialog`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html) class, which has both methods. Also, you've linked the old `AlertDialog.Builder` class, which, as you pointed out, you're not using. Look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AlertDialog.html), under "Inherited Methods".

Comment: @MikeM. i have imported 
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog; but i don't know where i have linked with old AlertDialog.Builder and how to get out from this problem

Comment: I meant you linked to the old class's documentation in your last comment. If you have the v7 class imported, then you're good to go. Just follow that example in the duplicate.

Comment: oh yes actually the link was http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AlertDialog.html

Answer (score 0):

Check this. it's run well in my case.May be your problem will solve using it.

```
 final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure,You wanted to make decision");
    final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    input.setLayoutParams(lp);
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(input);
    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            if (input.getText().toString().length() != 0) {
                alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(true);
              startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,SelectCatDialogue.class).putExtra("text",input.getText().toString()));
            } else {
                alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please Enter Text",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });

    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancle",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: you have finished activity on negative button. not works as i need