# Avoid dismiss on support.v7.app.AlertDialog when pressing button

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

In my application I am showing a custom `AlertDialog` for the user to enter the a string. When the user presses the positive button, there should be an `AsyncTask` in order to check the string provided by the user. If the check is successful I want to `dismiss()` the `AlerDialog`, on the other hand, if the check fails I want the `AlerDialog` to stay visible for the user to make the necessary corrections.

The problem is that **I have no idea how to avoid the `AlerDialog` to dismiss after click of any of the buttons** (I have checked with all of them).

None of the answers I have found here like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620444/how-to-prevent-a-dialog-from-closing-when-a-button-is-clicked) seem to work.

Here is my piece of code

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.generic_textinput_dialog, null);

final EditText editText = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.generic_dialog_text_editText);
editText.setHint("Username");

AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
dialogBuilder.setMessage("Share xxx");
dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Share", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick (DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        String sharingUser = editText.getText().toString();
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(sharingUser)) {
            doSomething();
        }

        actionMode.finish();
    }
});
dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
dialogBuilder.show();
```

**Any idea how to solve this issue?**

NOTES

- Obviously, I am not making use of `dialog.dismiss()` anywhere an even though the Dialog is dismissed after clicking any of the buttons.
- I am using  API v23.1.1.

Comment: If you do not want `AlertDialog` behavior, do not use `AlertDialog`. Create your own `Dialog` (or a dialog-themed activity).

Comment: I guess this would be the best option. I have spent too much time looking for a solution around the `AlertDialog`.

Answer (score 0):

You can always override the button on click listener to avoid the default functionality.

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
dialogBuilder.setMessage("Share xxx");
dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Share", null);
dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
dialogBuilder.show();
    Button positive = dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            positive.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                        String sharingUser = editText.getText().toString();
                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(sharingUser)) {
                          doSomething();
                        }

                        actionMode.finish();
                }
   });
```

Comment: This solution is the same as the answer I have mentioned in my question and it doesn't seem to work in my case: even setting the positive and negative button listeners to `null` the AlertDialog is dismissed after a click.