# how not to close a dialog after a button has been pressed

Tags: android

I have an activity that opens a dialog with 4 EditTexts, I need the user to enter all the edit texts to continue, how can I enforce the user to enter all fields?

**edit**
even if the user presses the back button
This is my code :

```
private void showEnterNamesDialog(final boolean edit){
    final AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.enter_names_dialog, null);
    dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

    final EditText[] plyrs_et = new EditText[4];

    plyrs_et[0] = (EditText)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.plyr1_et_dialog);
    plyrs_et[1] = (EditText)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.plyr2_et_dialog);
    plyrs_et[2] = (EditText)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.plyr3_et_dialog);
    plyrs_et[3] = (EditText)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.plyr4_et_dialog);

    if(edit){
        String[] names = gameList.getNames();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            plyrs_et[i].setText(names[i]);
        }

        dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            }
        });
    }

    dialogBuilder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.enter_players_names));

    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.submit_btn), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            String[] names = new String[4];

            for(int j = 0; j < 4 ; j++){
                names[j] = plyrs_et[j].getText().toString();
            }
            if(names[0].isEmpty() || names[1].isEmpty() || names[2].isEmpty() || names[3].isEmpty()) {
                Toast error = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.toast_alert), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                error.show();
            }else {
                if(edit){
                    //set the names in textViews
                    hp1.setText(names[0]);
                    hp2.setText(names[1]);
                    hp3.setText(names[2]);
                    hp4.setText(names[3]);

                    gameList.setNames(names);
                }else {
                    gameList.setNames(names);
                    setHeaderFooter(names);
                    listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    AlertDialog b = dialogBuilder.create();
    b.show();
}
```

This code only gives a Toast message but still closes the dialog.
Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620444/how-to-prevent-a-dialog-from-closing-when-a-button-is-clicked

Comment: we need to overide positive button ... see my answer below.. i have done the same in my project

Comment: thanks @Darussian i fixed it, but still the user can press the back button

Answer (score 0):

try this code by overriding positive button. It will not close the alert dialog if validation fails.

```
alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                // do nothing we overide this
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Committee Details");
        // create alert dialog
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        // show it
        alertDialog.show();
        alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(validate()) {
                    //your work after validation and close alert dialog
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
```

and in validate() method you can enforce validation

```
public boolean validate() {
    boolean t=true;
    if(cName.getText().toString().length()==0) {
        cName.setError("Commitee name cannot be Blank!!");
        t=false;
    }
    if(amount.length()==0){
        amount.setError("Amount cannot be Blank!!");
        t= false;
    }
    if(duration.getText().toString().length()==0) {
        duration.setError("Duration cannot be Blank!!");
        t= false;
    }
    if(noOfMember.getText().toString().length()==0) {
        noOfMember.setError("Number of Members cannot be Blank!!");
        t= false;
    }
    if(StartDate.length()<10) {
        StartDate.setError("Input Date");
        t = false;
    }
    return t;
}
```

Comment: @A Honey Bustard thanks for edit suggestion...