# Android highlight error field in Dialog

Tags: android, error-handling, dialog

For some reason **setError for EditText** in dialog is set, but the field is not highlighted. Dialog is loaded as separate view.

XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/pwdtext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/pwd_text"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <EditText
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/pwdtext"
        android:hint="@string/login">
        <requestFocus/>
    </EditText>
    <EditText
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/pwd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/login"
        android:hint="@string/pwd"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here goes **invokation of dialog**. Onclick listener works well. Via debugger have **`double-checked and getError()`** for both fields returns correct values but none of fields is highlighted. Dialog is also closed but I guess this shouldn't be while field has error:

```
private void showAlert(){
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    final View promptView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.auth_prompt,null);
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    dialogBuilder.setView(promptView);
    dialogBuilder.setCancelable(true);
    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK" , new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            EditText login = (EditText) ((AlertDialog) dialogInterface).findViewById(R.id.login);
            EditText pwd = (EditText) ((AlertDialog) dialogInterface).findViewById(R.id.pwd);
            //For simultaneous validation
            List<EditText> fields = new ArrayList<>();
            fields.add(login);
            fields.add(pwd);
            for(EditText field: fields){
                //Avoiding double checks on null+""
                String text = null;
                try{
                     text = field.getText().toString().trim();
                }catch (RuntimeException e){
                    text="";
                }
                if("".equals(text)){
                    field.setError("Please fill in the field");
                    ((AlertDialog) dialogInterface).show();
                }
            }
        }
     });
    dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            LOG.info("CANCEL Clicked");
            dialogInterface.cancel();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog dialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

Would appreciate any help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caused as Listener is created before dialog. Completely described here:
[How to prevent a dialog from closing when a button is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620444/how-to-prevent-a-dialog-from-closing-when-a-button-is-clicked)