# Kotlin / Anko prevent button from closing Alert Dialog

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog, anko

When using `positiveButton` and `negativeButton` in Anko's alert builder, it seems both of them result in closing the dialog, even if `dismiss()` is not called. Is there any way to keep the dialog open after clicking a button (if there are types other than `positiveButton`/`negativeButton`, that's fine too)?

```
alert {
    title = "Add Board"
    customView {
        ....
    }
    positiveButton("OK") { doSomeFunction() }
    negativeButton("Close"){}
}.show()
```

Comment: I suppose that's the default behavior of Android's AlertDialog.

Comment: @Bob ah, didn't realize that. I'll look and see if there are ways to override

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7636468/4586742

Comment: Thanks @Bob, overriding `onClickListener` after creating the dialog does the trick

Answer (score 7):

For anyone that may have this issue in the future, this is how you can accomplish this in Kotlin

```
val myAlert = alert {
    title = "Add Board"
    customView {
        ....
    }
    positiveButton("OK") { /*Keep blank, we'll override it later*/}
    negativeButton("Close"){}
    }.show()

//You can use BUTTON_NEGATIVE and BUTTON_NEUTRAL for other buttons
(myAlert as AlertDialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)
    .setOnclickListener{
        doSomeFunction()
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
alert {
  title = "Add Board"
  customView {
    ....
  }
  positiveButton("OK") { /*Keep blank, we'll override it later*/}
  negativeButton("Close"){}

  isCancelable = false // Disable close here
}.show()
```

Comment: this will no prevent the alert from being closed with the buttons