# Prevent dialog from closing when positiveButton is clicked and condition not true

Tags: java, android

So I have the following AppCompatDialogFragment. I want my positiveButton to close the dialog except when certain condition is true. I don't know how to achieve this.

```
public class ColorPicker extends AppCompatDialogFragment {
    private EditText editTextCode;
    private ColorPickerListener listener;
        /*other stuff*/

 public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.color_picker, null);
    builder.setView(view);
    builder.setTitle("Enter HEX code");
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });
    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            String code = editTextCode.getText().toString();
            if(code.length() != 6 && !code.matches("[0-9A-F]+")){
                //HERE I WANT TO PREVENT THE DIALOG FROM CLOSING!!
            }
            listener.applyHex(code);
        }
    });
      /* ... */
    return builder.create();
 }
```

Comment: Add your if-else condition inside positive button, don't call your listener outside

Comment: @RakshitNawani the thing is the value of code depends of editTextCode which changes its value depending of an user input. So I really need to get is value right when the positive button is clicked. And I don't think I can do calling the listener outside.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve it by overriding the `OnClickListener` of Positive Button as follows

```
        dialog.show();
        dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String code = editTextCode.getText().toString();
                if(code.length() != 6 && !code.matches("[0-9A-F]+")){
                    //Don't dismiss
                } else{
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
```

**Note:**

Remember to do it after `dialog.show()` is called, otherwise you will end up in getting `NullPointerException`.

Since you are using `AppCompatDialogFragment` do it as follows in `onResume()` of your `ColorPicker`

```
final AlertDialog dialog = (AlertDialog)getDialog();
 dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String code = editTextCode.getText().toString();
                if(code.length() != 6 && !code.matches("[0-9A-F]+")){
                    //Don't dismiss
                } else{
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: How can I get my dialog to be the value of the 'dialog' variable?

Comment: @Stackoverflowed `final AlertDialog dialog = (AlertDialog)getDialog();` in `onResume()`

Answer (score 0):

### override onResume() in AppCompatDialogFragment

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();    
    final AlertDialog d = (AlertDialog)getDialog();
    if(d != null)
    {
        Button positiveButton = (Button) d.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        positiveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        //your conditions are here
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

and do nothing in `setPositiveButtonclick` inside `onCreateDialog` just keep blank that

source: [Sogger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15619098/5773037)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Nothing needs to do much more you already getting the interface of dialog in your positive button click event you just need to put the code for dismissing in your else condition like bellow

```
    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        String code = editTextCode.getText().toString();
                        if(code.length() != 6 && !code.matches("[0-9A-F]+")){
                            //HERE I WANT TO PREVENT THE DIALOG FROM CLOSING!!
                        }else {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                     if(listener!=null){
                        listener.applyHex(code);}
                     }
                });
```

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't work. It still dismissed the dialog when I press 'Ok'.