# Prevent Dialog Box from being dismissed

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

There is a Dialog Box, how can I prevent it from being dismissed? I want not only the user enter a username but also prevent him/her from leaving the box empty?

Comment: Specify your own OnClickListeners using the `AlterDialog.Builder`'s `setPositiveButton`/`setNegativeButton`. You could also change the buttons' enable state dynamically based on the input fields' contents.

Comment: You can also make customise dialog box, it wont be dismissed until you do it yourself

Comment: Duplicate OF [How to prevent a dialog from closing when a button is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620444/how-to-prevent-a-dialog-from-closing-when-a-button-is-clicked).

Answer (score 3):

```
dialog.setCancelable(false);
```

This function call will make your dialog dismissable by touch on the outside of the dialog. Moreover, you can control the actions of the positive and negative buttons. However if you have custom dialog with edit text in it then you should check the string that you get from edittext when user click the positive or negative button and **not** call `dialog.dismiss();` method if string is empty. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it prevents user from dismissing the dialogue box

```
myDialog.setCancelable(false);
```