# Face Recognition with OpenCv, NDK and Android

Tags: java, android, opencv

I was trying to run this code to take a photo and recognize tho photo owner, at first the user clicks the button Train and takes a picture than enter its name, after that he clicks on Recognize button and take a picture if the picture was saved the apps recognize its face if not it shows unknown person for example. The app runs good but when it crashes sometimes with this error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.facedetection.app, PID: 7442
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {com.facedetection.app/com.facedetection.app.TrainActivity}: CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: OpenCV(4.0.0-pre) E:\AssemCourses\opencv-master\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp:235: error: (-215:Assertion failed) s >= 0 in function 'setSize'
    ]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4852)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4915)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:211)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1759)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
     Caused by: CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: OpenCV(4.0.0-pre) E:\AssemCourses\opencv-master\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp:235: error: (-215:Assertion failed) s >= 0 in function 'setSize'
    ]
        at org.opencv.face.FaceRecognizer.train_0(Native Method)
        at org.opencv.face.FaceRecognizer.train(FaceRecognizer.java:133)
        at com.facedetection.app.TrainActivity.trainfaces(TrainActivity.java:95)
        at com.facedetection.app.TrainActivity.onStop(TrainActivity.java:351)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStop(Instrumentation.java:1305)
        at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:6777)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4847)
```

Here is the classe mentionned in the error logcat:

Class TrainActivity.java:

```
    import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.stetho.Stetho;

import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfRect;

import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.face.Face;
import org.opencv.face.FaceRecognizer;
import org.opencv.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier;

import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Set;
import static org.opencv.objdetect.Objdetect.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE;

/**
 * Created by Assem Abozaid on 6/2/2018.
 */

public class TrainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2 {
    private static String TAG = TrainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private CameraBridgeViewBase openCVCamera;
    private Mat rgba,gray;
    private CascadeClassifier classifier;
    private MatOfRect faces;
    private static final int PERMS_REQUEST_CODE = 123;
    private ArrayList<Mat> images;
    private ArrayList<String> imagesLabels;
    private Storage local;
    private String[] uniqueLabels;
    FaceRecognizer recognize;
    private boolean trainfaces() {
        if(images.isEmpty())
            return false;
        List<Mat> imagesMatrix = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++)
            imagesMatrix.add(images.get(i));
        Set<String> uniqueLabelsSet = new HashSet<>(imagesLabels); // Get all unique labels
        uniqueLabels = uniqueLabelsSet.toArray(new String[uniqueLabelsSet.size()]); // Convert to String array, so we can read the values from the indices

        int[] classesNumbers = new int[uniqueLabels.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < classesNumbers.length; i++)
            classesNumbers[i] = i + 1; // Create incrementing list for each unique label starting at 1
        int[] classes = new int[imagesLabels.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < imagesLabels.size(); i++) {
            String label = imagesLabels.get(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < uniqueLabels.length; j++) {
                if (label.equals(uniqueLabels[j])) {
                    classes[i] = classesNumbers[j]; // Insert corresponding number
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        Mat vectorClasses = new Mat(classes.length, 1, CvType.CV_32SC1); // CV_32S == int
        vectorClasses.put(0, 0, classes); // Copy int array into a vector

        recognize = LBPHFaceRecognizer.create(3,8,8,8,200);
        recognize.train(imagesMatrix, vectorClasses);
        if(SaveImage())
            return true;

        return false;
    }
    public void showLabelsDialog() {
        Set<String> uniqueLabelsSet = new HashSet<>(imagesLabels); // Get all unique labels
        if (!uniqueLabelsSet.isEmpty()) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Select label:");
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    images.remove(images.size()-1);
                }
            });
            builder.setCancelable(false); // Prevent the user from closing the dialog

            String[] uniqueLabels = uniqueLabelsSet.toArray(new String[uniqueLabelsSet.size()]); // Convert to String array for ArrayAdapter
            Arrays.sort(uniqueLabels); // Sort labels alphabetically
            final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, uniqueLabels) {
                @Override
                public @NonNull
                View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
                    TextView textView = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                    if (getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet))
                        textView.setTextSize(20); // Make text slightly bigger on tablets compared to phones
                    else
                        textView.setTextSize(18); // Increase text size a little bit
                    return textView;
                }
            };
            ListView mListView = new ListView(this);
            mListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); // Set adapter, so the items actually show up
            builder.setView(mListView); // Set the ListView

            final AlertDialog dialog = builder.show(); // Show dialog and store in final variable, so it can be dismissed by the ListView

            mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    addLabel(arrayAdapter.getItem(position));
                    Log.i(TAG, "Labels Size "+imagesLabels.size()+"");
                }
            });
        } else {
            showEnterLabelDialog();
        }

    }
    private void showEnterLabelDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Please enter your name:");

        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        builder.setView(input);

        builder.setPositiveButton("Submit", null); // Set up positive button, but do not provide a listener, so we can check the string before dismissing the dialog
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                images.remove(images.size()-1);
            }
        });
        builder.setCancelable(false); // User has to input a name
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

        // Source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7636468/2175837
        dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShow(final DialogInterface dialog) {
                Button mButton = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
                mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        String string = input.getText().toString().trim();
                        if (!string.isEmpty()) { // Make sure the input is valid
                            // If input is valid, dismiss the dialog and add the label to the array
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            addLabel(string);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        // Show keyboard, so the user can start typing straight away
        dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);

        dialog.show();
    }
    private void addLabel(String string) {
        String label = string.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase(Locale.US) + string.substring(1).trim().toLowerCase(Locale.US); // Make sure that the name is always uppercase and rest is lowercase
        imagesLabels.add(label); // Add label to list of labels
        Log.i(TAG, "Label: " + label);

    }
    public boolean SaveImage() {
        File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "TrainedData");
        path.mkdirs();
        String filename = "lbph_trained_data.xml";
        File file = new File(path, filename);
        recognize.save(file.toString());
        if(file.exists())
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    public void cropedImages(Mat mat) {
        Rect rect_Crop=null;
        for(Rect face: faces.toArray()) {
            rect_Crop = new Rect(face.x, face.y, face.width, face.height);
        }
        Mat croped = new Mat(mat, rect_Crop);
        images.add(croped);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.train_main);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        Stetho.initializeWithDefaults(this);

        if (hasPermissions()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.i(TAG, "Permission Granted Before");

        }
        else {
            requestPerms();
        }

        openCVCamera = (CameraBridgeViewBase)findViewById(R.id.java_camera_view);
        openCVCamera.setCameraIndex(CameraBridgeViewBase.CAMERA_ID_FRONT);
        openCVCamera.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
        openCVCamera.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
        local = new Storage(this);
        Button detect = (Button)findViewById(R.id.take_picture_button);
        detect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(gray.total() == 0)
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Can't Detect Faces", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                classifier.detectMultiScale(gray,faces,1.1,3,0|CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, new Size(30,30));
                if(!faces.empty()) {
                    if(faces.toArray().length > 1)
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Mutliple Faces Are not allowed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    else {
                        if(gray.total() == 0) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Empty gray image");
                            return;
                        }
                        cropedImages(gray);
                        showLabelsDialog();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Face Detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }else
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unknown Face", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
    @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
    private boolean hasPermissions(){
        int res = 0;
        //string array of permissions,
        String[] permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA};

        for (String perms : permissions){
            res = checkCallingOrSelfPermission(perms);
            if (!(res == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    private void requestPerms(){
        String[] permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            requestPermissions(permissions,PERMS_REQUEST_CODE);

        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        boolean allowed = true;
        switch (requestCode){
            case PERMS_REQUEST_CODE:
                for (int res : grantResults){
                    // if user granted all permissions.
                    allowed = allowed && (res == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                }
                break;
            default:
                // if user not granted permissions.
                allowed = false;
                break;
        }
        if (allowed){
            //user granted all permissions we can perform our task.
            Log.i(TAG, "Permission has been added");
        }
        else {
            // we will give warning to user that they haven't granted permissions.
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) || shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) ||
                        shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private BaseLoaderCallback callbackLoader = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch(status) {
                case BaseLoaderCallback.SUCCESS:
                    faces = new MatOfRect();
                    openCVCamera.enableView();

                    images = local.getListMat("images");
                    imagesLabels = local.getListString("imagesLabels");

                    break;
                default:
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(openCVCamera != null)
            openCVCamera.disableView();


    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (images != null && imagesLabels != null) {
            local.putListMat("images", images);
            local.putListString("imagesLabels", imagesLabels);
            Log.i(TAG, "Images have been saved");
            if(trainfaces()) {
                images.clear();
                imagesLabels.clear();
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        if(openCVCamera != null)
            openCVCamera.disableView();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        if(OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "System Library Loaded Successfully");
            callbackLoader.onManagerConnected(BaseLoaderCallback.SUCCESS);
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Unable To Load System Library");
            OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION, this, callbackLoader);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
        rgba = new Mat();
        gray = new Mat();
        classifier = FileUtils.loadXMLS(this, "lbpcascade_frontalface_improved.xml");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStopped() {
        rgba.release();
        gray.release();
    }

    @Override
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        Mat mGrayTmp = inputFrame.gray();
        Mat mRgbaTmp = inputFrame.rgba();

        int orientation = openCVCamera.getScreenOrientation();
        if (openCVCamera.isEmulator()) // Treat emulators as a special case
            Core.flip(mRgbaTmp, mRgbaTmp, 1); // Flip along y-axis
        else {
            switch (orientation) { // RGB image
                case ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
                case ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT:
                    Core.flip(mRgbaTmp, mRgbaTmp, 0); // Flip along x-axis
                    break;
                case ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
                case ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE:
                    Core.flip(mRgbaTmp, mRgbaTmp, 1); // Flip along y-axis
                    break;
            }
            switch (orientation) { // Grayscale image
                case ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
                    Core.transpose(mGrayTmp, mGrayTmp); // Rotate image
                    Core.flip(mGrayTmp, mGrayTmp, -1); // Flip along both axis
                    break;
                case ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT:
                    Core.transpose(mGrayTmp, mGrayTmp); // Rotate image
                    break;
                case ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE:
                    Core.flip(mGrayTmp, mGrayTmp, 1); // Flip along y-axis
                    break;
                case ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE:
                    Core.flip(mGrayTmp, mGrayTmp, 0); // Flip along x-axis
                    break;
            }
        }
        gray = mGrayTmp;
        rgba = mRgbaTmp;
        Imgproc.resize(gray, gray, new Size(200,200.0f/ ((float)gray.width()/ (float)gray.height())));
        return rgba;
    }
}
```

The Lines of Errors mentionned in the logcat refers to those java code lines:

In TrainActivity.java:

```
    recognize = LBPHFaceRecognizer.create(3,8,8,8,200);
    recognize.train(imagesMatrix, vectorClasses);
```

And

```
     if(trainfaces()) {
            images.clear();
            imagesLabels.clear();
        }
```

Do you guys have any idea about this problem and how to fix it?

PS: I am a beginner with OpenCv.

Comment: The error message says that the assertion `s >= 0 in function 'setSize'` failed, so `s` must be less than zero. I would take a look at the sizes of `imageMatrix` and `vectorClasses` and any pertinent sizes of the objects contained within them.

Comment: imageMatrix is an arraylist of training images, and it takes the size of images that user takes, And classes is an arraylist of images labels and Vectorclasses is transformation of classes to a vector! i don't know where the error is! please check trainfaces() method.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by reset preferences onCreate TrainActivity

```
// -------------------------------
// reset preferences
local = new Storage(this);
images = new ArrayList<>();
imagesLabels = new ArrayList<>();
local.putListMat("images", images);
local.putListString("imagesLabels", imagesLabels);
// -------------------------------
```