# Dialog dismiss on yes button

Tags: android, dialog

I'm using class that extends from dialog to change a password. When I press yes button the dialog is dismissed. I want the dialog to not dismiss if I have wrong inputs.

This my code

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_yes:
            if ((!TextUtils.isEmpty(newpass.getText().toString())) && oldpass.getText().toString().equals(Login_Activity.e.getPassword())) {
                Login_Activity.e.password=newpass.getText().toString();
                user.child(Login_Activity.e.getId()).setValue(Login_Activity.e);
                dismiss();
            } else {
                yes.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
            }
        case R.id.btn_no:
            dismiss();
            break;
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `break` statement for `case R.id.btn_yes`. According to [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html):

> The break statements are necessary because without them, statements in switch blocks fall through: All statements after the matching case label are executed in sequence, regardless of the expression of subsequent case labels, until a break statement is encountered

In your situation, button with id `btn_yes` is clicked, then either block of code in `if` or `else` is executed then program flow continues to execution of code in `case R.id.btn_no` because it wasn't stopped with break in matching case.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_yes:
            if ((!TextUtils.isEmpty(newpass.getText().toString())) && oldpass.getText().toString().equals(Login_Activity.e.getPassword())) {
                Login_Activity.e.password=newpass.getText().toString();
                user.child(Login_Activity.e.getId()).setValue(Login_Activity.e);
                dismiss();
            } else {
                yes.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
            }
            break; // add this
        case R.id.btn_no:
            dismiss();
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the auto-dismiss behaviour manually, depending on your dialog class.

The answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620444/how-to-prevent-a-dialog-from-closing-when-a-button-is-clicked) offer several ways to achieve this, like replacing the button's onClick listener, or even disabling it dynamically if your inputs are invalid.