# How to prevent dismiss of Time Picker Dialog after time selection?

Tags: android, android-timepicker

I am using android's `TimePickerDialog` this way

```
val tpd = TimePickerDialog(this, { dialog, h, min -> 
 // I want to dismiss the dialog only if the validations succeed
}, 12, 15, false)
tpd.show()
```

How do I prevent it from getting auto dismissed after user selects a time? I want to run my validations before I can dismiss the time picker dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Since `TimePickerDialog` extends `AlertDialog` you can get the positive Button and modify its click listener [This way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620444/how-to-prevent-a-dialog-from-closing-when-a-button-is-clicked).

But the problem here is you will not access to the `TimePicker` widget because you need it to get the time for validation. Becasue if you override the positive button click your listener will not get called and `mTimePicker` field is private in `TimePickerDialog` . Sure you can access it by reflection but that's not right way to do stuff .

As a solution create a Custom `AlertDialog` . that way you can have control over selection.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/TimePicker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>


 val alert = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        alert.setView(R.layout.time_picker)
        alert.setPositiveButton("OK"
        ) { dialog, which -> {
                // validate here
        } }

        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel"
        ) { dialog, which -> {
            dialog.dismiss()
        } }
        alert.show()
```

Use [This Approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620444/how-to-prevent-a-dialog-from-closing-when-a-button-is-clicked) to prevent `AlertDialog` from getting closed and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
abstract class TimePickerDialog2(
    context: Context,
    hourOfDay: Int, minute: Int, is24Hour: Boolean
) {
    private val impl = DialogImpl(context, { view, hourOfDay, minute ->
        if (onTimeSet(view, hourOfDay, minute)) {
            dismiss()
        }
    }, hourOfDay, minute, is24Hour)

    fun show() { impl.show() }
    fun dismiss() { impl.dismiss() }

    /** Called when user presses OK button. Return [true] to close dialog, [false] otherwise. */
    abstract fun onTimeSet(view: TimePicker, hourOfDay: Int, minute: Int)
            : Boolean

    private class DialogImpl(
        context: Context,
        listener: OnTimeSetListener,
        hourOfDay: Int, minute: Int, is24Hour: Boolean
    ) : TimePickerDialog(context, listener, hourOfDay, minute, is24Hour) {

        var skipDismiss = false
        override fun dismiss() { if (skipDismiss) { skipDismiss = false } else { super.dismiss() } }
        override fun onClick(dialog: DialogInterface, which: Int) {
            super.onClick(dialog, which)
            skipDismiss = (which == BUTTON_POSITIVE)
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
object : TimePickerDialog2(this, 12, 15, false) {
    override fun onTimeSet(view: TimePicker, hourOfDay: Int, minute: Int): Boolean {
        if (/* the validations succeed */) {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}.show()
```

This implementation uses some hacky tricks to work around. Better to use custom `AlertDialog` solution for this, as @ADM suggested above.